# multcomp Tukey-Kramer

Tags: r, statistics, posthoc, lsmeans

I have an experiment that is unbalanced where at three sites (L, M, H) we measure a parameter (`met`) in four different vegetation types (a, b, c, d). All vegetation types are present at all three sites. Vegetation types are replicated 4 times at L and M and 8 times at H.

Therefore a simple anova and TukeyHSD will not work. Packages Agricolae (`HSD.test`) and DTK (`DTK.test`) are only working for one way designs, and then there is multcomp... Does the Tukey test in the `mcp` function calculate Tukey-Kramer contrasts, or does it give the regular Tukey contrasts? I presume the first to be the case because the package is geared towards testing multiple comparisons for unbalanced designs, but I am unsure because p-values produced with both approaches are virtually the same. What test would then be appropriate?

Also, are there more suitable approaches towards doing such a two way anova for unbalanced data sets?

```
library(multcomp)

(met     <-  c(rnorm(16,6,2),rnorm(16,5,2),rnorm(32,4,2)))
(site    <-  c(rep("L", 16), rep("M", 16), rep("H", 32)))
(vtype   <-  c(rep(letters[1:4], 16), rep(letters[1:4], 16), rep(letters[1:4], 32)))

dat  <-  data.frame(site, vtype, met)

# using aov and TukeyHSD
aov.000  <-  aov(met ~ site * vtype, data=dat)
summary(aov.000) 
TukeyHSD(aov.000) 

# using Anova, and multcomp
lm.000     <-  lm(met ~ site * vtype, data=dat)
summary(lm.000)
library(car)
Anova.000  <-  Anova(lm.000, data=dat)

dat$int  <-  with(dat, interaction(site, vtype, sep = "x"))
lm.000   <-  lm(met ~ int, data = dat)
summary(lm.000)
summary(glht.000 <- glht(lm.000, linfct = mcp(int = "Tukey")))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For unbalanced data, anova with type III SS may be used instead of type I SS [1]. Calculation of type III anova in R [2]:

```
model <- (met ~ site * vtype)
defopt <- options()
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
print(drop1(aov(model),~.,test="F"))
options <- defopt
```

For unbalanced data, pairwise comparisons of adjusted means may be used. Calculation in R [4]:

```
library(lsmeans)
print(lsmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ site)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ vtype)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ site | vtype)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model, list(pairwise ~ vtype | site)), adjust = c("tukey"))
```

Lines 2 and 3 compare levels of main effects "site" and "vytpe". Lines 4 and 5 compare levels of one factor at each level of another factor separately.

I hope this helps.

References

[1] Miliken and Johnsen. 2009. Analysis of messy data. Volume 1.

[2] http://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html

[3] http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf